# Is there a way to change theme colour for a pre existing word doc using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, doc

i need a way to apply theme colours of a doc in python by reading an existing document and changing the colour theme using python
like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXJ4w.png

is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `PyAutoGui` may be the solution. You can either set pre-made movesets for the computer to move the mouse or you could use pictures for the module to recognise to press.